# Read from Avro and Write to multiple HBase in Mapper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, avro

I have used `MultiTableOutputFormat` and successfully written to Multiple HBase tables in `TableReducer`. But how to achieve that in `Mapper` only job?

I tried using `TableMapper` but it has only `<KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>` and not `<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>`. So I couldn't read in text files.

My Mapper is reading from Text/Avro file and processing it before pushing to HBase. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can open an HBase connection and write the PUT operations yourself inside the Mapper you implement

Comment: HBase connection creation is heavy-weight operation. Is this possible to share HBase connection among mappers so that connection instance can be re-utilized?

Comment: since each mapper runs in its own JVM (and only occasionally on the same server) - then the answer is no

Comment: It's correct that each mapper runs on its own JVM. I think if I serialize the hbase connection object and set it in `Configuration` class inside driver's program and again de-serialize it in `setup()` method of mapper to get original connection object, then it can be done. A nice example is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983741/passing-objects-to-mapreduce-from-a-driver/26984356).

Comment: connections are not serializable objects as they actually create connections between specific ips and ports. You can create the a connection once per mapper (when it is initialized)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz